# Verify Auth0 ID Token - which secret do I need to use

Tags: go, jwt, auth0

I am using Auth0 to generate a JWT ID Token for the users. Now I would like to verify this ID Token in my go backend. I just want to **extract the identity** of the user from this key and check if it was **created by my application** in Auth0.

I am using the [chi](https://github.com/go-chi/chi) router with the [jwtauth](https://github.com/go-chi/jwtauth) middleware. That is a lightweight wrapper around [jwx](https://github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx).

The documentation says I should do the following:

```golang
    tokenAuth = jwtauth.New("RS256", []byte("secret"), nil)
```

I have tried several things as "secret", like my Auth0 Application's client secret or the Signing Certificate. But none of them seems to work. I double-checked if I am using the correct Signature Algorithm.

It always results in `token is unauthorized`.

```golang
    r.Route("/users", func(r chi.Router) {
        r.Use(jwtauth.Verifier(tokenAuth))
        //r.Use(jwtauth.Authenticator)
        r.Post("/info", usersService.InfoHandler)
    })
```

In the handler I try to get the token:

```golang
    token, _, err := jwtauth.FromContext(r.Context())
    fmt.Println("token", token)
    fmt.Println("error", err)
```

Comment: if you have a token signed with "RS256" (RSA-SHA256), you need a RSA public key. This line `jwtauth.New("RS256", []byte("secret")` might work for "HS256" (HMAC-SH256), but certainly not for "RS256".

Comment: @jps Thanks, that was a good hint. I found out, that I can pass the complete jwks as a string into that library. This get's me a step further - now it says "token is unauthorized". I need to dig deeper into what is now happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now created a middleware to do this. It's pretty straightforward forward and I think there is no need to use the jwtauth middleware.

The best thing seems to use the [JSON Web Key Set (JWKS)](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-key-sets). It contains all information to verify a JWT.

```golang
package auth0

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwk"
    "github.com/lestrrat-go/jwx/jwt"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "net/http"
)

var (
    ErrInvalidToken = fmt.Errorf("invalid token")
    ErrNoToken      = fmt.Errorf("no token found")
)

type middleware struct {
    keySet   jwk.Set
    audience string
    issuer   string
}

type AuthUser struct {
    ID    string `json:"id"`
    Email string `json:"email"`
}

type userKeyType string

const userKey = userKeyType("user")

type Middleware interface {
    AuthenticateUser(next http.Handler) http.Handler
}

var _ Middleware = &middleware{}

func NewMiddleware(issuer string, audience string) (middleware, error) {
    // TODO implement auto rotation/refresh
    keySet, err := jwk.Fetch(context.Background(), fmt.Sprintf("%s.well-known/jwks.json", issuer))
    if err != nil {
        return middleware{}, err
    }

    return middleware{
        keySet:   keySet,
        audience: audience,
        issuer:   issuer,
    }, nil

}

func (m *middleware) AuthenticateUser(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        authHeader := r.Header.Get("Authorization")
        if authHeader == "" {
            log.Debug("no authorization header found")
            http.Error(w, ErrNoToken.Error(), http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }
        bearerToken := authHeader[7:]
        if bearerToken == "" {
            log.Error("no bearer token found")
            http.Error(w, ErrNoToken.Error(), http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }

        token, err := jwt.Parse([]byte(bearerToken), jwt.WithKeySet(m.keySet))
        if err != nil {
            log.Error("error parsing token")
            http.Error(w, ErrInvalidToken.Error(), http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }

        if err := jwt.Validate(token,
            jwt.WithAudience(m.audience),
            jwt.WithIssuer(m.issuer)); err != nil {
            log.Error("error validating token")
            http.Error(w, ErrInvalidToken.Error(), http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }

        emailValue, ok := token.Get("email")
        if !ok {
            log.Error("error no email found")
            http.Error(w, ErrInvalidToken.Error(), http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }

        email, ok := emailValue.(string)
        if !ok {
            log.Error("error email not a string")
            http.Error(w, ErrInvalidToken.Error(), http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }

        if token.Subject() == "" && email == "" {
            log.Error("error no subject or email found")
            http.Error(w, ErrInvalidToken.Error(), http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }

        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), userKey, AuthUser{
            ID:    token.Subject(),
            Email: email,
        })

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}

func GetUserFromContext(ctx context.Context) (AuthUser, error) {
    user, ok := ctx.Value(userKey).(AuthUser)
    if !ok {
        return AuthUser{}, fmt.Errorf("could not get user from context")
    }
    return user, nil
}
```